LWC Component data issue for a particular user
I have created an LWC component that shows data of logged in user's invoice value and opportunity pipeline. I have given apex class access to system admin and sales user profiles. There is a particular user who has sales user profile who was unable to see any data on his component. I did a thorough check on his permissions, sharing settings etc., everything was good but I'm not sure why is he not able to see any data on his component. Interestingly another user who has same permissions as him is able to access the component. Can someone please help me understand what could be the reason for this behaviour.


Try logging in as another user and see if you can see any Invoice and Opportunity records? Also what is the sharing setting of the apex class (with or without sharing) and what is the org wide default of these 2 objects?

Hi Prem,
Thank you very much for responding. I have tried logging in as another user, they do have invoice and opportunity records.
Sharing setting of apex class is with sharing and I have even tried to remove sharing setting on apex class to see if it's causing the issue.
Interestingly, I ran some reports and commented out logic for opportunity pipeline and the component is working fine. However, I want to have both opportunity and invoice data on my overview component. I did cross check records but couldn't find the issue.

I found the issue. For users who were not able to get data on the component had opportunity records without amount. I have updated my logic
if (opp.Amount != null && opp.ExpectedRevenue != null) {
Decimal oppValue = opp.Amount;
Decimal oppExpValue = opp.ExpectedRevenue;
